# When does $0=\int f(x)\psi(x)\,dx$ for all $f\in L^1(G)$ imply that $\psi=0$

Tags: measure-theory, lp-spaces, locally-compact-groups, haar-measure

Let $G$ be a locally compact group with Haar measure $dx$.

I am wondering what conditions a function $\psi$ must satisfy so that the following holds.

$\int f(x)\psi(x)\,dx=0$ for all $f\in L^1(G)\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \Rightarrow\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $ $\psi=0\ \  (a.e.)$

And how do I proove that the implication is true? 
I hope someone can help, I have no idea of where to start..

Comment: This is always true if $\psi$ is measurable and vanishes outside of a sigma finite set. The second condition is in particular fulfilled if the group is sigma finite (sigma compact) to begin with. For the proof choose $f$ to be suitable indicator functions.

Comment: @ Phoemuex You have to include conditions that ensure existence of $\int f \psi$. The best condition I can think of is $\psi \in L^{\infty}$.

Comment: The question  doesn't have much to do with locally compact groups and Haar measure. It is a basic measure theory question and I think the tags are not appropriate.

Comment: @Kavi: Yes and no. As far as I am concerned, the condition $\int f\psi =0$ for all $f\in L^1$ includes the implicit assumption that the integral exists for all such $f$, so I don't have to place additional assumptions to ensure this :)